# Cannot select child element on Wordpress menu

Tags: wordpress, select, menu, element

I have been trying to use a menu on Wordpress and it has been working so far. The problem is that you cannot select any of the child elements in the menu.
They will appear when you hover over the parent. But when you move the pointer away from the parent then the child vanishes.

I'm still relatively new to all of this so if anyone can help that would be awesome!

And thanks in advance.
The demo site is here;
http://www.tudorlodgeholidayhomes.co.uk/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the Css Selector in your DevTools F12 in chrome. try and search in console $$("#menu-item-22 > a > span") This will identify your child element.

You can use this with 
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#menu-item-22 > a > span");

Hope this helps.

Thanks
Sourabh

Comment: Thank you for your help. I got it to work in the end by adding another div behind it. I'm to entiretly sure how it's working. But I'll take it.